# How to replace the arrow by tirangle in mat-paginator?

Tags: html, angular, mat-pagination

I created a mat-paginator like that

[image]

but I want to modify the icons in the form of a triangle (as shown in the photo) => i want replace the arrow by tirnagle

[image]

how do i change the icon to a triangle ?

file.ts :

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
```

file.html:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15, 20]"></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material Pagination - How to replace first and last icons with text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191704/angular-material-pagination-how-to-replace-first-and-last-icons-with-text)

Comment: @HenryWoody, no, I want to replace the arrow by triangle

Comment: Slightly different question, but the answer will work for you